# std deque is surprisingly slow

Tags: c++, performance, stack, deque

I just find out that standard std deque is really slow when comparing with my "home-made" version of stack that use pre-allocated array.
This is code of my stack:

```
template <class T>
class FastStack
{    
public:
    T* st;
    int allocationSize;
    int lastIndex;

public:
    FastStack(int stackSize);
    FastStack();
    ~FastStack();

    inline void resize(int newSize);
    inline void push(T x);
    inline void pop();
    inline T getAndRemove();
    inline T getLast();
    inline void clear();
};

template <class T>
FastStack<T>::FastStack()
{
    lastIndex = -1;
    st = NULL;
}

template <class T>
FastStack<T>::FastStack(int stackSize)
{
    st = NULL;
    this->allocationSize = stackSize;
    st = new T[stackSize];
    lastIndex = -1;
}

template <class T>
FastStack<T>::~FastStack()
{
    delete [] st;
}

template <class T>
void FastStack<T>::clear()
{
    lastIndex = -1;
}

template <class T>
T FastStack<T>::getLast()
{
    return st[lastIndex];
}

template <class T>
T FastStack<T>::getAndRemove()
{
    return st[lastIndex--];
}

template <class T>
void FastStack<T>::pop()
{
    --lastIndex;
}

template <class T>
void FastStack<T>::push(T x)
{
    st[++lastIndex] = x;
}

template <class T>
void FastStack<T>::resize(int newSize)
{
    if (st != NULL)
        delete [] st;
    st = new T[newSize];
}
```

.
**I run this simple benchmark for deque:**

```
std::deque<int> aStack;
int x;

HRTimer timer;
timer.Start();

for (int i = 0; i < 2000000000; i++)
{
    aStack.push_back(i);
    x = aStack.back();
    if (i % 100 == 0 && i != 0)
        for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++)
            aStack.pop_back();
}

double totalTime = timer.Stop();
stringstream ss;
ss << "std::deque " << totalTime;
log(ss.str());
```

.
**Using std stack with vector as container (as 'Michael Kohne' suggested)**

```
std::stack<int, std::vector<int>> bStack;
int x;

HRTimer timer;
timer.Start();

for (int i = 0; i < 2000000000; i++)
{
    bStack.push(i);
    x = bStack.top();
    if (i % 100 == 0 && i != 0)
        for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++)
            bStack.pop();
}

double totalTime = timer.Stop();
stringstream ss;
ss << "std::stack " << totalTime;
log(ss.str());
```

.
**And the same one for my FastStack:**

```
FastStack<int> fstack(200);
int x;

HRTimer timer;
timer.Start();

for (int i = 0; i < 2000000000; i++)
{
    fstack.push(i);
    x = fstack.getLast();
    if (i % 100 == 0 && i != 0)
        for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++)
            fstack.pop();
}

double totalTime = timer.Stop();
stringstream ss;
ss << "FastStack " << totalTime;
log(ss.str());
```

.
**The results after 4 runs are as follows:**
deque 15.529
deque 15.3756
deque 15.429
deque 15.4778

stack 6.19099
stack 6.1834
stack 6.19315
stack 6.19841

FastStack 3.01085
FastStack 2.9934
FastStack 3.02536
FastStack 3.00937

The results are in seconds and I was running the code on Intel i5 3570k (on default clock). I used VS2010 compiler with all optimizations that are available.
I know that my FastStack has a lot of limitations but there are plenty situations, where it could be used and when it can give nice boost! (I used it in one project where I get 2x speed up comparing to std::queue).
So now my question is:
<del>Are there any other "inhibitors" in C++ that everybody use but no one knows about them?</del>
EDIT: I don't want to be offensive, I'm just curious if you know some unknown "speedups" like this.

Comment: Asking about a list of "inhibitors" like this is not constructive.

Comment: After you build the deque, call [resize](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/deque/resize/) on it.  See if it makes a big speed difference.  My guess is that a large portion of the speed gained/lost is from the deque class trying to "smartly" manage memory by changing size.

Comment: You're missing braces on your if statement.

Comment: If "no one knows about them" how are they to be reported here?

Comment: I'll pretend I didn't see your last sentence and treat this as a legitimate performance question.

Comment: Your "stack" doesn't offer random access or fast insertion at both ends. How is this a sensible comparison? I'm sure your Toyota requires less fuel than my tank, but also it doesn't have a big cannon.

Comment: On a side note, I'm not sure how fair it is to compare a stack to a double-ended queue.  Try the stdlib `stack` class and see if that makes a difference as well.

Comment: `std::deque` is designed for constant time insertion at both ends. A fairer comparison would be to extend your stack class (granted, it wouldn't be a stack anymore) to allow for that. Or compare with `std::vector`.

Comment: Additionally note that your manual implementation is broken, the implicitly generated copy constructor/assignment will cause undefined behavior... and the `int` constructor should be `explicit`... it is rather easy to get the details wrong even for simple classes: prefer prebuilt/tested solutions :)

Comment: @Rapptz - the code is missing **unnecessary** braces on the if statements.

Comment: If there are situations where `std::deque` is too slow, and where you don't need the double-ended behaviour ... you _chose the wrong container_. You could just use `std::vector` directly for what you're doing (admittedly it would be nice if you could reserve a vector-based stack).

Answer (score 23):

You are comparing apples and oranges. The dequeue is DOUBLE-ENDED, which requires it to be quite a bit different internally than the simple stack you've implemented. Try running your benchmark against an `std::stack<int, std::vector<int> >` instead and see how you do. std::stack is a container adapter, and if you use a vector as the underlying container, it should be nearly as fast as your home-grown implementation.

The one down side is that the std::stack implementation doesn't have a way for you to pre-set the size, so in situations where you KNOW what the max size needs to be, it'll be a little slower initially as it has to re-allocate several times. After that, it will be pretty much the same.

Comment: Same benchmark using vector as container for stack: 6.19099 6.1834  6.19315 6.19841. The benchmark puts only 100 numbers in stack in same time so reallocation shouldn't be so big problem.

Comment: So do one iteration with std::stack (to set the size) and _then_ do the timed loop (using the same pre-grown stack). How does it look now?

Comment: Ok so I did one loop and add 100 numbers, then another loop and delete them (just before line 'HRTimer timer'). Using debugger I check stack capacity after these loops and it was 141 and remains 141 all the time (because only 100 elements are added in same time) and the results are worse - 6.65823. I did some experiments so i change loops to go up to 1000 and then results was 6.34 and then I changed it to 1000000 and results was 6.35 (capacity was 1049869). I don't know why result changing when changing unused capacity space (I mean the difference between 100 and 1000).

Comment: I did one more experiment, I put Sleep(5000) right after the loops, now when loops go up to 100, results gets little better: 6.129 (average).

Comment: I'd expect the std::stack to be slower than your implementation, remember that it's got to account for the possibility of extending the container at push_back time. Looking at your code again, I'm not too surprised that you are still much faster, because on we still aren't comparing apples to apples - your container doesn't have all the overhead needed to support auto-extending, or even the overhead of not running off into the adjacent memory block. So yes, your container SHOULD be faster, and if that's important to your application, great! Just don't screw up the sizing or you're toast.

Answer (score 15):

If you know the maximum amount of elements that will be in the stack at any given time you should use a `std::vector` on which you reserve the capacity upfront. Even if you don't know the capacity, for a stack you should use a `std::vector` which will grow a few times (higher cost than a preallocated vector when growing) but never shrink, so after some time it will stop allocating memory.

The issue with performance is that `std::deque` will allocate blocks as needed, and deallocate them when they are no longer needed (following some strategy), so if you fill and clear the `std::deque` often there will be allocations and deallocations continuously.

Comment: You are right. Performance gets better from 15 s to 6 s but it's still really slow when comparing with simple 'stack' class like the one I make. I know that my version has no error handling or other features but it's faster and also allows random access due to public members...

Comment: @klerik: What compiler and flags are you using? The only reason a `std::vector` would be slower than your handcrafted code is if you are using checked iterators, or compiling in debug mode with no function inlining. Performance testing is not trivial, you have to really understand what you are doing and the implications of the test or else you might not be able to interpret the results appropriately.

Comment: I was using VS2010, all benchmarks was running on Release build with parameters /O2, /Oi, /Ot, /Oy-, /GL and /Ob2, so any suitable function should be inline and all code optimizations should work. I was using debug only to find out stack capacity. But I was using checked iterators so I turned it off right now but looks like it make no difference at all.

Comment: @klerik: Your implementation and a vector for which you preallocate with `reserve` are the same solution. There should not be any noticeable change in performance. I suggest you try to analyze where the performance impact is, as that is really unexpected.

Comment: I created new question, there are some results even from other users... [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12704314/std-stack-performance-issues)