# std stack performance issues

Tags: c++, windows, performance, stack

Recently I was trying to do some performance benchmarks, comparing `std::stack<int, std::vector<int>>` and my own simple implementation of stack (that use pre-allocated memory). Now I’m experiencing some strange behavior.

**First thing I want to ask** is this line in stack benchmark code:

```
//  std::vector<int> magicVector(10);
```

When I uncomment this line, performance rise about 17% (benchmark time drops from 6.5 to 5.4 seconds). But the line should have no impact on the rest of the program because it's not modifying any others members. Besides, it doesn't matter if it is vector of int or vector of double...

**Second thing I want to ask** is big performance difference between my stack implementation and `std::stack`. I was told that `std::stack` should be as fast as my stack but results shows that my "FastStack" is twice as fast.

**Results** (with uncommented performance increasing line):
stack 5.38979
stack 5.34406
stack 5.32404
stack 5.30519
FastStack 2.59635
FastStack 2.59204
FastStack 2.59713
FastStack 2.64814

These results come from release build from VS2010 with /O2, /Ot, /Ob2 and others default optimizations. My CPU is Intel i5 3570k with default clock (3.6 GHz for one thread).

I put all code in one file so anyone can easily test it.

```
#define _SECURE_SCL 0

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stack>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  Purpose:    High Resolution Timer
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

class HRTimer
{
public:
    HRTimer();
    double GetFrequency(void);
    void Start(void) ;
    double Stop(void);
    double GetTime();

private:
    LARGE_INTEGER start;
    LARGE_INTEGER stop;
    double frequency;
};

HRTimer::HRTimer()
{
    frequency = this->GetFrequency();
}

double HRTimer::GetFrequency(void)
{
    LARGE_INTEGER proc_freq;
    if (!::QueryPerformanceFrequency(&proc_freq))
        return -1;
    return proc_freq.QuadPart;
}

void HRTimer::Start(void)
{
    DWORD_PTR oldmask = ::SetThreadAffinityMask(::GetCurrentThread(), 0);
    ::QueryPerformanceCounter(&start);
    ::SetThreadAffinityMask(::GetCurrentThread(), oldmask);
}

double HRTimer::Stop(void)
{
    DWORD_PTR oldmask = ::SetThreadAffinityMask(::GetCurrentThread(), 0);
    ::QueryPerformanceCounter(&stop);
    ::SetThreadAffinityMask(::GetCurrentThread(), oldmask);
    return ((stop.QuadPart - start.QuadPart) / frequency);
} 

double HRTimer::GetTime()
{
    LARGE_INTEGER time;
    ::QueryPerformanceCounter(&time);
    return time.QuadPart / frequency;
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  Purpose:    Should be faster than std::stack
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

template <class T>

class FastStack
{
public:
    T* st;
    int allocationSize;
    int lastIndex;

public:
    FastStack(int stackSize);
    ~FastStack();

    inline void resize(int newSize);
    inline void push(T x);
    inline void pop();
    inline T getAndRemove();
    inline T getLast();
    inline void clear();
};

template <class T>
FastStack<T>::FastStack( int stackSize )
{
    st = NULL;
    this->allocationSize = stackSize;
    st = new T[stackSize];
    lastIndex = -1;
}

template <class T>
FastStack<T>::~FastStack()
{
    delete [] st;
}

template <class T>
void FastStack<T>::clear()
{
    lastIndex = -1;
}

template <class T>
T FastStack<T>::getLast()
{
    return st[lastIndex];
}

template <class T>
T FastStack<T>::getAndRemove()
{
    return st[lastIndex--];
}

template <class T>
void FastStack<T>::pop()
{
    --lastIndex;
}

template <class T>
void FastStack<T>::push( T x )
{
    st[++lastIndex] = x;
}

template <class T>
void FastStack<T>::resize( int newSize )
{
    if (st != NULL)
        delete [] st;
    st = new T[newSize];
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  Purpose:    Benchmark of std::stack and FastStack
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
#if 1
    for (int it = 0; it < 4; it++)
    {
        std::stack<int, std::vector<int>> bStack;
        int x;

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)   // after this two loops, bStack's capacity will be 141 so there will be no more reallocating
            bStack.push(i);
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            bStack.pop();
    //  std::vector<int> magicVector(10);           // when you uncomment this line, performance will magically rise about 18%

        HRTimer timer;
        timer.Start();

        for (int i = 0; i < 2000000000; i++)
        {
            bStack.push(i);
            x = bStack.top();
            if (i % 100 == 0 && i != 0)
                for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++)
                    bStack.pop();
        }

        double totalTime = timer.Stop();
        cout << "stack " << totalTime << endl;
    }
#endif

    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#if 1
    for (int it = 0; it < 4; it++)
    {
        FastStack<int> fstack(200);
        int x;

        HRTimer timer;
        timer.Start();

        for (int i = 0; i < 2000000000; i++)
        {
            fstack.push(i);
            x = fstack.getLast();
            if (i % 100 == 0 && i != 0)
                for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++)
                    fstack.pop();
        }

        double totalTime = timer.Stop();
        cout << "FastStack " << totalTime << endl;
    }
#endif

    cout << "Done";
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

.
**EDIT:** Since everybody talks about my really bad implementation of my stack I want to set things right. I created that stack in few minutes and I implemented just few features that I currently needed. It was never meant to be a replacement of std::stack :) or save to use in all cases. The only goal was to achieve maximum speed and correct results. I'm sorry about this misunderstanding… I just want to know few answers…

Comment: You amended your question with that disclaimer regarding your broken implementation ~4hrs after it was pointed out to you. That's certainly plenty of time to _fix the implementation_, render all the comments obsolete that point out its flaws, and bring the discussion back to performance issues. You have decided to play elsewhere, so I'll vote to close this question as "silly benchmark attempt". Oh wait, this doesn't exist. So "not constructive" it will be: "We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or specific expertise." Fits well enough, I think.

Comment: @sbi you already voted to close the question and now it's closed so chill out :)

Comment: @sbi And why should I changing that implementation? Even this "broken" version meets my needs and my solution that is using it works perfectly fine without single exceptions but with noticeable boost. It shouldn't be perfect, it was made to be fast.

Comment: Just because you do not run into the bugs in your current code, this is _not_ a good reason to disregard those bugs. (But it takes bitter experience to learn this.) Also, one would think that to _render the comments obsolete that point out its flaws and bring the discussion back to performance issues_ might be reason enough. Anyway, I mainly wanted to explain why I considered this close-worthy, because two followed my reasoning, and now that it lacks all the discussions at the question itself, it might not be as obvious that the question solicited debate, arguments, and extended discussion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The many comments (and even answers) focus on the risks in your implementation. Yet the question stands.

As directly demonstrated below rectifying the perceived code shortcomings would **not** change anything significant about the performance.

Here is the OP's code modified to be (A) safe, and (B) supporting the same operations as `std::stack`, and (C) reserving buffer space also for the `std::stack`, in order to clarify things for those who mistakenly believe that this stuff matters for the performance:

```
#define _SECURE_SCL 0
#define _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <algorithm>        // std::swap
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stack>
#include <stddef.h>         // ptrdiff_t
#include <type_traits>      // std::is_pod
using namespace std;

#undef UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#include <Windows.h>

typedef ptrdiff_t   Size;
typedef Size        Index;

template< class Type, class Container >
void reserve( Size const newBufSize, std::stack< Type, Container >& st )
{
    struct Access: std::stack< Type, Container >
    {
        static Container& container( std::stack< Type, Container >& st )
        {
            return st.*&Access::c;
        }
    };

    Access::container( st ).reserve( newBufSize );
}

class HighResolutionTimer
{
public:
    HighResolutionTimer();
    double GetFrequency() const;
    void Start() ;
    double Stop();
    double GetTime() const;

private:
    LARGE_INTEGER start;
    LARGE_INTEGER stop;
    double frequency;
};

HighResolutionTimer::HighResolutionTimer()
{
    frequency = GetFrequency();
}

double HighResolutionTimer::GetFrequency() const
{
    LARGE_INTEGER proc_freq;
    if (!::QueryPerformanceFrequency(&proc_freq))
        return -1;
    return static_cast< double >( proc_freq.QuadPart );
}

void HighResolutionTimer::Start()
{
    DWORD_PTR oldmask = ::SetThreadAffinityMask(::GetCurrentThread(), 0);
    ::QueryPerformanceCounter(&start);
    ::SetThreadAffinityMask(::GetCurrentThread(), oldmask);
}

double HighResolutionTimer::Stop()
{
    DWORD_PTR oldmask = ::SetThreadAffinityMask(::GetCurrentThread(), 0);
    ::QueryPerformanceCounter(&stop);
    ::SetThreadAffinityMask(::GetCurrentThread(), oldmask);
    return ((stop.QuadPart - start.QuadPart) / frequency);
} 

double HighResolutionTimer::GetTime() const
{
    LARGE_INTEGER time;
    ::QueryPerformanceCounter(&time);
    return time.QuadPart / frequency;
}

template< class Type, bool elemTypeIsPOD = !!std::is_pod< Type >::value >
class FastStack;

template< class Type >
class FastStack< Type, true >
{
private:
    Type*   st_;
    Index   lastIndex_;
    Size    capacity_;

public:
    Size const size() const { return lastIndex_ + 1; }
    Size const capacity() const { return capacity_; }

    void reserve( Size const newCapacity )
    {
        if( newCapacity > capacity_ )
        {
            FastStack< Type >( *this, newCapacity ).swapWith( *this );
        }
    }

    void push( Type const& x )
    {
        if( size() == capacity() )
        {
            reserve( 2*capacity() );
        }
        st_[++lastIndex_] = x;
    }

    void pop()
    {
        --lastIndex_;
    }

    Type top() const
    {
        return st_[lastIndex_];
    }

    void swapWith( FastStack& other ) throw()
    {
        using std::swap;
        swap( st_, other.st_ );
        swap( lastIndex_, other.lastIndex_ );
        swap( capacity_, other.capacity_ );
    }

    void operator=( FastStack other )
    {
        other.swapWith( *this );
    }

    ~FastStack()
    {
        delete[] st_;
    }

    FastStack( Size const aCapacity = 0 )
        : st_( new Type[aCapacity] )
        , capacity_( aCapacity )
    {
        lastIndex_ = -1;
    }

    FastStack( FastStack const& other, int const newBufSize = -1 )
    {
        capacity_ = (newBufSize < other.size()? other.size(): newBufSize);
        st_ = new Type[capacity_];
        lastIndex_ = other.lastIndex_;
        copy( other.st_, other.st_ + other.size(), st_ );   // Can't throw for POD.
    }
};

template< class Type >
void reserve( Size const newCapacity, FastStack< Type >& st )
{
    st.reserve( newCapacity );
}

template< class StackType >
void test( char const* const description )
{
    for( int it = 0; it < 4; ++it )
    {
        StackType st;
        reserve( 200, st );

        // after this two loops, st's capacity will be 141 so there will be no more reallocating
        for( int i = 0; i < 100; ++i ) { st.push( i ); }
        for( int i = 0; i < 100; ++i ) { st.pop(); }

        // when you uncomment this line, std::stack performance will magically rise about 18%
        // std::vector<int> magicVector(10);

        HighResolutionTimer timer;
        timer.Start();

        for( Index i = 0; i < 1000000000; ++i )
        {
            st.push( i );
            (void) st.top();
            if( i % 100 == 0 && i != 0 )
            {
                for( int j = 0; j < 100; ++j ) { st.pop(); }
            }
        }

        double const totalTime = timer.Stop();
        wcout << description << ": "  << totalTime << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    typedef stack< Index, vector< Index > > SStack;
    typedef FastStack< Index >              FStack;

    test< SStack >( "std::stack" );
    test< FStack >( "FastStack" );

    cout << "Done";
}
```

Results on this slow-as-molasses Samsung RC530 laptop:

```
[D:\dev\test\so\12704314]
> a
std::stack: 3.21319
std::stack: 3.16456
std::stack: 3.23298
std::stack: 3.20854
FastStack: 1.97636
FastStack: 1.97958
FastStack: 2.12977
FastStack: 2.13507
Done
[D:\dev\test\so\12704314]
> _
```

And similarly for Visual C++.

Now let's look at a typical implementation of `std::vector::push_back`, which is called by `std::stack<T, std::vector<T>>::push` (in passing, I know of only 3 programmers who have ever used this indentation style, namely PJP, Petzold and myself; I now, since 1998 or thereabouts, think it's horrible!):

```
void push_back(const value_type& _Val)
    {   // insert element at end
    if (_Inside(_STD addressof(_Val)))
        {   // push back an element
        size_type _Idx = _STD addressof(_Val) - this->_Myfirst;
        if (this->_Mylast == this->_Myend)
            _Reserve(1);
        _Orphan_range(this->_Mylast, this->_Mylast);
        this->_Getal().construct(this->_Mylast,
            this->_Myfirst[_Idx]);
        ++this->_Mylast;
        }
    else
        {   // push back a non-element
        if (this->_Mylast == this->_Myend)
            _Reserve(1);
        _Orphan_range(this->_Mylast, this->_Mylast);
        this->_Getal().construct(this->_Mylast,
            _Val);
        ++this->_Mylast;
        }
    }
```

I *suspect* that the measured inefficiency lies at least partly in all the stuff going on there, and *perhaps* it's also a matter of automatically generated safety checks.

For a debug build the `std::stack` performance is so extremely ungood that I gave up waiting for any result.

---

**EDIT**: following Xeo’s comment below I updated `push` to check for "self-push" in the case of buffer reallocation, by factoring that out as a separate function:

```
void push( Type const& x )
{
    if( size() == capacity() )
    {
        reserveAndPush( x );
    }
    st_[++lastIndex_] = x;
}
```

Mysteriously, although `reserveAndPush` is *never called* in this testing, it affects the performance – due to code size not fitting cache?

```
[D:\dev\test\so\12704314]
> a
std::stack: 3.21623
std::stack: 3.30501
std::stack: 3.24337
std::stack: 3.27711
FastStack: 2.52791
FastStack: 2.44621
FastStack: 2.44759
FastStack: 2.47287
Done
[D:\dev\test\so\12704314]
> _
```

---

**EDIT 2**: DeadMG showed that the code must be buggy. I believe the problem was a missing `return`, plus the expression computing new size (twice zero is still zero). He also pointed out that I forgot to show `reserveAndPush`. Should be:

```
void reserveAndPush( Type const& x )
{
    Type const xVal = x;
    reserve( capacity_ == 0? 1 : 2*capacity_ );
    push( xVal );
}

void push( Type const& x )
{
    if( size() == capacity() )
    {
        return reserveAndPush( x );    // <-- The crucial "return".
    }
    st_[++lastIndex_] = x;
}
```

Comment: A good part of the slowness might well come from the check on whether an element of the vector itself is `push_back`ed into this vector. It's needed, as otherwise `v.push_back(v[0])` would break when the vector has to reallocate, but a stack *normally* doesn't have to concern itself with that, except when `s.push(s.top())` is called.

Comment: In your code, since your `top` returns a copy, this is also a non-issue... but again, fails to implement the same functionality. Also, as I mentioned in the chat, your `FastStack` doesn't destruct the elements (which is not needed for PODs), which is a different functionality than `std::stack` again. Try a custom allocator that simply assigns when asked to construct and has a noop `destroy` method.

Comment: That's a nifty bit of testing code. FWIW, without alterations, the OP's code for `FastStack` only ~7% faster than `std::stack` on a Q9550, gcc 4.6.2 -O3 -march=native (**[full disclosure](http://liveworkspace.org/code/052a99e5bc1d5f5745faab9ffda060d9)**, timed externally)

Comment: This answer is needlesly long for what boils down to your penultimate sentence, 'std::stack is slow because it is doing a lot of checking'. It also fails to handle one of the key points of the OPs question, why does that one line affect timing so much?

Comment: @thecoshman you missed the other point: if you manually adjust for pre-allocation as in the FastStack sample, the difference disappears. Also, see my own timings ^^

Comment: Xeo: re push of element in stack, mysteriously it does impact on the performance even though that code isn't executed. possibly because of the code size (cache). re "fails to implement same functionality", that's incorrect. `top` returns a copy in the OP's code, in `std::stack`, and in the code in this answer; no difference.

Comment: @sehe: no, it's not the case that pre-allocation matters. the code above pre-allocates for both types of stack (that is, also for `std::stack`).

Comment: The *usage* of `std::stack::top` in the OPs code might make a copy, but that's not inherent to `std::stack`, since that returns a reference from `top`, which *might* be used as an argument to `push`. Also, you still destruct the elements in the `std::stack` case.

Comment: Your code still doesn't function correctly in the case of non-default-constructability- nor does it correctly function when `operator=` throws, as you increment the top and assign in the same expression.

Comment: @Xeo: it really doesn't matter except for the code size (or whatever it is that is at play: the code you see above in the EDIT does handle the self push case, and i checked now whether returning a reference had any performance effect, and it didn't.

Comment: @DeadMG: you're wrong. a POD is always default-constructible, and assignment for POD can't throw. the code above doesn't provide the non-POD implementation and it's not interesting, because by the principle of "you don't pay for what you don't use" `std::stack` *should* be specialized for POD, if that has any performance gain, in a quality implementation.

Comment: But I did determine that your FastStack has a bug in it. I altered your code a bit, and FastStack crashes, whereas `std::stack` is fine. Visual Studio reports heap corruption. [here](http://pastebin.com/qGsJQv6k) is my altered test.

Comment: No, that's not the bug at all. The bug is when capacity is 0, you only ever reserve 2*capacity(), which is still 0. Thus you never increase the buffer size from 0.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf since no more answers are possible in here (due to recent close), I checked yours as the most constructive and most useful, thank you :)

Comment: Every bug fix you make brings it closer and closer to the MSVC stdlib time. Now you're within 10% (accounting for what I believe to be a small bug in MSVC's pop() where it checks for empty() unnecessarily) according to the timing results from this machine with the test case I showed. I think that if you keep testing it, you'll find a couple more bugs, and when you fix them, they'll basically be identical.

Comment: @DeadMG: With your test case I get "std::stack: 3.27996; std::stack: 3.15607; std::stack: 3.17407; std::stack: 3.13552; FastStack: 2.37243; FastStack: 2.40678; FastStack: 2.49941;  FastStack: 2.32981" So **the** bug fix (thanks for checking & reporting!) does not reduce the performance difference. Also, the percentage seems rather higher than 10%; roughly 33% or thereabouts.

Comment: That's what the "accounting for small bug in pop" is for.

Comment: the code with reverseAndPush factored out is slower because compiler gets a bit confused when inlining stuff because reverseAndPush calls push. If you help it a bit by inlining things manually the speed increases again.

Answer (score 6):

Your method implementations are all broken. Ignoring the copy constructor and other missing operations, your `push` invokes UB if you push too much, and your `resize` is plainly broken as it does not copy over the previous data *and* it's not exception safe *and* your push isn't exception safe *and* you invoke too many copies *and* your `getAndRemove` isn't exception safe *and* you don't destruct popped off elements *and* you don't construct new elements properly, only assign them *and* you needlessly default-construct when created, and there are probably more I haven't found.

Basically, your class is extremely and hideously unsafe in every imaginable respect, destroys the user's data at the drop of a hat, calls all the wrong functions on `T`, and will go crying in a corner the instant an exception is thrown anywhere.

It's a giant pile of bad and the fact that it's "faster" than `std::stack` is, well, entirely irrelevant, since all you've proven is that if you don't have to meet the requirements, you can go as fast as you like, which we all already knew.

Fundamentally, as sbi said, you clearly don't understand the semantics of `std::stack`, nor important C++ aspects like exception safety, and the ways in which your code fails to work correctly is what makes it execute faster. You've got a long way to go, my friend.

Comment: +1 Best deconstruction of OP's code I've ever read. :P

Comment: @DeadMG :-D ok first of all, I'm not trying to create new stack that will replace std stack. I'm aware all this missing features :). BUT! if you use it right (if you know the maximum size, if you never call pop on empty stack and etc...) it will bring you good boost (if my results are correct).  But I still want to know the answer on my first question - why is that piece of code affecting results. Btw, thx for reply :)

Comment: @klerik duh, your stack does something different than std stack (basically, the difference is that yours breaks down at the slightest breeze and the std one just works. That's why they don't have the same performance characteristic As someone else once said, it is easy to make a fast program that outputs garbage.

Comment: -1 The concerns about safety are irrelevant wrt. what's asked for. The safety doesn't impact the performance of the code.

Comment: It sure does. Not having to copy over when you resize is saving cycles. Not having to check for bounds saves cycles. He's saving time by simply not implementing the same function.

Comment: The lack of safety checking does matter, it's like asking why the cake with out any eggs or butter does not taste as good

Comment: @DeadMG: your hypothesis is wrong. i measured. you find that in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Contrary to a `std::stack` using `std::vector`, your stack does not reallocate when it runs out of space, but simply blows up the planet. Allocation, however, is a huge drain on performance, so skipping on that will certainly gain you performance.

However, in your place I'd grab one of the well-aged `static_vector` implementations [floating on the web](http://www.google.com/#q=%22static_vector%22) and stuff that into `std::stack` in place of `std::vector`. That way, you skip all the performance-hungry dynamic memory handling, but you have a valid stack implementation with a container for memory handling underneath that's *very* likely to be much better than what you come up with.

Comment: +1 for static_vector (could std::array be used, or is that too _un-container-like_?)

Comment: @sehe AFAIK `std::array`, because being designed to be used as a static array, doesn't have `push_back()` etc., so cannot be used. Those `static_vector` thingies, OTOH, are meat to be a drop-in replacement for `std::vector` so they support the whole interface.